# How to convert space separated file into tab separated?

Tags: command-line

my file pheno_Mt.txt looks like this:

```
IID pheno
1000017 -9
1000025 -9
1000038 1
1000042 -9
1000056 -9
```

So it is space separated and I would like to convert it into tab separated.

I tried:

```
cat pheno_Mt.txt | tr ' ' '\t' > pheno_Mtt.txt
```

and this:

```
sed 's/ /\t/g' pheno_Mt.txt > pheno_Mtt.txt
```

but this just tab separated the first line, the rest stay space separated.

Machine I am running this on is:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"

od -c pheno_Mt.txt > outt
head outt
0000000   I   I   D       p   h   e   n   o  \n   1   0   0   0   0   1
0000020   7       -   9  \n   1   0   0   0   0   2   5       -   9  \n
0000040   1   0   0   0   0   3   8       1  \n   1   0   0   0   0   4
0000060   2       -   9  \n   1   0   0   0   0   5   6       -   9  \n
0000100   1   0   0   0   0   7   4       -   9  \n   1   0   0   0   0
0000120   8   9       -   9  \n   1   0   0   0   0   9   3       1  \n
0000140   1   0   0   0   1   0   8       -   9  \n   1   0   0   0   1
0000160   1   5       -   9  \n   1   0   0   0   1   2   7       2  \n
0000200   1   0   0   0   1   3   0       -   9  \n   1   0   0   0   1
0000220   4   9       -   9  \n   1   0   0   0   1   5   1       -   9

od -c pheno_Mtt.txt > outtt
head outtt
0000000   I   I   D  \t   p   h   e   n   o  \n   1   0   0   0   0   1
0000020   7  \t   -   9  \n   1   0   0   0   0   2   5  \t   -   9  \n
0000040   1   0   0   0   0   3   8  \t   1  \n   1   0   0   0   0   4
0000060   2  \t   -   9  \n   1   0   0   0   0   5   6  \t   -   9  \n
0000100   1   0   0   0   0   7   4  \t   -   9  \n   1   0   0   0   0
0000120   8   9  \t   -   9  \n   1   0   0   0   0   9   3  \t   1  \n
0000140   1   0   0   0   1   0   8  \t   -   9  \n   1   0   0   0   1
0000160   1   5  \t   -   9  \n   1   0   0   0   1   2   7  \t   2  \n
0000200   1   0   0   0   1   3   0  \t   -   9  \n   1   0   0   0   1
0000220   4   9  \t   -   9  \n   1   0   0   0   1   5   1  \t   -   9
```

Comment: `tr` should work, maybe it's not a regular ASCII space character?

Comment: Show the output of `od -c pheno_Mt.txt`

Comment: Otherwise it could be a visual problem, tab might look like space when it happens to be just right. Your numbers are 7 characters... tab-width 8 (or 4), you can't tell visually unless your editor highlights it.

Comment: I updated my post with the output of :od -c pheno_Mt.txt

Comment: Do the same for Mtt.txt should show \t

Comment: I just updated the post with od -c pheno_Mtt.txt > outtt. Does this look to you as tab separated file?

Comment: The new file is clearly tab delimited according to the `od` output. Why do you think it is not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ tr ' ' '\t' <pheno_Mt.txt
IID     pheno
1000017 -9
1000025 -9
1000038 1
1000042 -9
1000056 -9
```

This *looks* as if the `tr` command only did something to the first line of the file, but since the output of a tab brings the cursor up to the next multiple of eight position on the screen, and since this happens to be exactly one space after the 7 character number, the effect is that the tabs on the other lines *appears* to only be a single space.

Another way of doing this, by the way, which is not dependent on the number of spaces used in the original file, is

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{ print $1, $2 }' pheno_Mt.txt
IID     pheno
1000017 -9
1000025 -9
1000038 1
1000042 -9
1000056 -9
```

This uses `awk` to output two tab-delimited columns read from the whitespace-delimited input.

Or, for any number of columns,

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{ $1=$1; print }' pheno_Mt.txt
IID     pheno
1000017 -9
1000025 -9
1000038 1
1000042 -9
1000056 -9
```

This forces `awk` to re-form the whole record by modifying the first field.  A plain `print` would print the record with tabs as delimiters.

Comment: could you elaborate more on re-form the whole record on `awk -v OFS='\t' '{ $1=$1; print }'`. I don't quite understand. thanks

Comment: @alex If no field is changed, `awk` won't output the fields with the custom `OFS` value between them. To get `awk` to print all fields with our `OFS` value between them, we need to "provoke" a change to one of the fields. We do that with `$1 = $1`, which just sets the first field to itself.

Answer (score 2):

With the usual 8-space tabs, this

```
$ printf '1234567 abc\n'
1234567 abc
```

is indistinguishable from this:

```
$ printf '1234567\tabc\n'
1234567 abc
```

And all your numbers just so happen to be 7 digits long.

The od output shows a `\t` on each line, so the actual data is fine.